# Setting up a registration function in views.py (error message when I try to run the server)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having this error message come up when I try to run the server:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserProfileInfoForm needs updating.

Can anyone tell me what it means so I can correct my code, please? Here is a screenshot:

[Screenshot of views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcyys.png)

Comment: Can you post your code for `UserProfileInfoForm` here? It looks like thats where the error is

Comment: This error means that you have not defined which fields of model you want to show when ModelForm will be rendered at front-end. Please refer to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you modelForm, create Meta class, and add fields, or excloude variable, and you should be good after that.